# Add running number in select statement based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I have a view `receipt_data` that includes `contract_no` and `receipt_no` columns - something like this:

```
contract_no | receipt_no | Amount
------------+------------+---------
1176        | ABMN1024   |  100 
1176        | ABMN1027   |  767
1176        | ABMN1027   |  345
NULL        | MNDF7132   |  389
NULL        | NULL       |  673
1046        | MDGF2344   |  454
```

I need to query this view with running number added to it. Running number should be added as following.

```
 run_no    |contract_no | receipt_no | Amount
 ----------+------------+------------+--------    
  1        | 1176       | ABMN1024   |  100 
  2        | 1176       | ABMN1027   |  767
           | 1176       | ABMN1027   |  345
  3        | NULL       | MNDF7132   |  389
           | NULL       | NULL       |  673
  4        |1046        | MDGF2344   |  454
```

The running number must be like

1. Add running number to unique `contract_no + receipt_no`
2. If `receipt_no` has value then return running number
3. If `receipt_no` is null, there's no need to add running number, skip it

Is it possible to script like this? Please help

Comment: have you tried using `dense_rank()` ?

Comment: You cannot do this.  You are assuming that your data has some sort of ordering, but none of the data shows the ordering.  If you have such a column, I would suggest asking another question with more complete data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using `row_number()` analytic function

```
select 
case when receipt_no is not null
then
row_number()over(order by (select null))
else null end as run_no,t.* from
table_name t
```

Comment: This gives only 1 as running number :(

Comment: Thank you for you help. But this satisfies only condition 3rd. and running number is not in order . It is like 1, 3, 2. Also it shows running number for duplicate receipt_no, contract_no pairs